# Minimum number of circles to completely cover a sphere

Tags: integration, area, spheres

I've encountered a problem which I have some idea of solving but am befuddled on how to proceed. Here is the full problem:

> Suppose that you wish to cover a 1-km radius, spherical planet with
>   Wi-Fi signal. In order to do this, you have an unlimited number of
>   antennae that cover circular, 35-meter radii areas and transmit
>   signal between themselves as long as the intersection of their areas
>   is equal to or greater than 10m^2. What is the minimum amount of
>   antennae needed to completely cover the planet with Wi-Fi?

So far, I've reasoned that the problem basically boils down to finding an algorithm that will minimise the number of circular areas needed to completely cover the sphere, as long as each circle intersects another with an area of at least 10m^2. However, this resembles nothing I've been currently studying, so I have no idea where to start. I'm assuming integrals must somehow come into play, but have no idea how that logic would go.

Comment: You can begin by getting a lower bound on number of circles needed using area of sphere divided by area of one spherical circle (cap).

Comment: Not exactly the same problem, but related: deals with how to place n circles of radius r onto a sphere, to maximize area covered: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/53553.pdf "Transition from Circle Packing to Covering on a Sphere: The Odd Case of 13 Circles." P. W. Fowler and T. Tarnai. Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences, 455 (Dec. 8, 1999), pp. 4131-4143.